# Matplotlib: how to set the current figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is hopefully a simple question but I can't figure it out at the moment. I want to use matplotlib to show 2 figures and then use them interactively. I create the figures with:

```
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl

f1 = pl.figure()
f2 = pl.figure()
```

and can use the MATLAB-like pyplot interface to plot and draw in both figures. With

```
current_figure = pl.gcf()
```

I can determine the currently active figure for the pyplot interface, depending on which figure I clicked in. Now I want to draw something to the first figure with the pyplot interface but the current figure can be either of them. So is there something like

```
pl.set_current_figure(figure)
```

or any workaround? (I know that I can use the object oriented interface but for interactive stuff just using commands like plot(x, y) is much nicer)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can simply set figure `f1` as the new current figure with:

```
pl.figure(f1.number)
```

Another option is to give names (or numbers) to figures, which might help make the code easier to read:

```
pl.figure("Share values")
# ... some plots ...
pl.figure("Profits")
# ... some plots ...

pl.figure("Share values")  # Selects the first figure again
```

In fact, figure "numbers" can be strings, which are arguably more explicit that simple numbers.

**PS**: The pyplot equivalent of `pylab.figure()` is `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()`.

**PPS**: `figure()` now accepts a `Figure` object, so you should be able to activate figure `f1` with `figure(f1)`.

Comment: Is there a good way to do this using matplotlib.figure.Figure instead of pylab??

Comment: @tylerthemiler: Yes, but that would be `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()`.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing with axes, just use `pylab.sca(my_axis)` ("set current axis").

Comment: I personally prefer using symbols and naming the symbols well (e.g., `share_values_fig` instead of `f1`), rather than passing strings. I find it's easier to detect when you have misspelled a symbol name, since Python will complain, than when you have mistyped a string, which assumes that matplotlib will complain (which it might do in this case—I don't know—but some functions would perhaps just create a new figure if it didn't recognize the string since earlier). But both options work, I guess.

Answer (score 19):

Give each figure a number:

```
f1 = pl.figure(1)
f2 = pl.figure(2)
# use f2
pl.figure(1) # make f1 active again
```