# Matplotlib: how to show a figure that has been closed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function which returns a `Figure` created with `pyplot`. This function closes the figure before returning it. If I didn't close it, showing it would be very easy with just `plt.show()`, but let us assume I cannot do that.

I can easily save the returned `Figure` to a file, but I cannot find the way to display it (i.e.: have a popped window showing the figure).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt                                                


def new_figure():                                                                   
    fig = plt.figure()                                                              
    plt.plot([0, 1], [2, 3])                                                        
    plt.close(fig)                                                                  
    return fig                                                                      


fig = new_figure()                                                                  
fig.savefig('output.svg')                                                           
fig.show()
```

How could I show the figure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When `plt.close` is called on a `figure` instance, what is actually destroyed is the graphical interface (the *FigureManager*) that is used to show the figure on-screen (see comment by JoeKington at [Matplotlib: re-open a closed figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621017/matplotlib-re-open-a-closed-figure/9621119#9621119)). So the figure instance still exists and has not been destroyed. To show the figure on-screen again, we would have to reconstruct, in some way, an interface to replace the one that has been destroyed when calling `plt.close(fig)`.

This can be done by simply creating a new figure with `plt.figure()`, "stealing" its manager, and use it to display the figure that we want to show on-screen. Alternatively, it is possible to reconstruct manually an interface to display the figure with a GUI Toolkit. I provide an example with [PySide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PySide) using the Qt4Agg backend. Moreover, there is a nice example that shows how this can be done with Tkinter (TkAgg) here : http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html (I've tested this approach also and it works).

### Dummy figure approach:

This solution is based on [how to close a show() window but keep the figure alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419626/how-to-close-a-show-window-but-keep-the-figure-alive/25422314#25422314) and [Obtaining the figure manager via the OO interface in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065753/obtaining-the-figure-manager-via-the-oo-interface-in-matplotlib/13066723#13066723). The GUI toolkit that is used to construct the graphical interface for showing the figure on-screen depends on the [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) that is used by matplotlib. If the backend used  is *TkAgg*, *TkInter* will give some warning in Python 2.7 that can be ignored (see this [post on python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue20567#msg229224)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def new_figure(): 

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0, 1], [2, 3])
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig

def show_figure(fig):

    # create a dummy figure and use its
    # manager to display "fig"

    dummy = plt.figure()
    new_manager = dummy.canvas.manager
    new_manager.canvas.figure = fig
    fig.set_canvas(new_manager.canvas)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fig = new_figure()
    show_figure(fig)

    plt.show()
```

### Pyside approach:

This consists in reconstructing a GUI with a new canvas and toolbar to display the `fig` instance on-screen.

**Important Note:** The code below must be executed in a new dedicated Python console (press F6) if run from [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/), since Spyder is also a Qt application that starts it's own QApplication (see [PySide Qt script doesn't launch from Spyder but works from shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709262/pyside-qt-script-doesnt-launch-from-spyder-but-works-from-shell/10711239#10711239)).

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PySide import QtGui
import sys

def new_figure():

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([0, 1], [2, 3])
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig   

class myFigCanvas(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, fig, parent=None):
        super(myFigCanvas, self).__init__(parent)

        #---- create new canvas and toolbar --

        canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(canvas, self)

        #---- setup layout of GUI ----

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()    
        grid.addWidget(canvas, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(toolbar, 1, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    fig = new_figure()   
    new_canvas = myFigCanvas(fig) 
    new_canvas.show()    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: mpl really should have a 'reshow' method on figures/figure_managers

Comment: Just in case anyone else encounters this, be warned that while this works, it breaks plot interactivity -- the toolbar (cursor position, zoom, etc.) is still linked to the original figure, not the new one. I thought maybe copying more attributes than `new_manager.canvas.figure = fig` from the old manager to the new one might work, but I haven't been able to solve this yet.

Comment: @CliffKerr, I'm facing that exact problem. After closing a figure, I overlay some other plots on that fig, and when I use the "Dummy figure approach" to show that fig again, toolbar is useless. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, sorry @pcremades!

Comment: Instead of re-using a manager, maybe we can create a new one directly with "plt._backend_mod.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num=25, figure=fig)". It works with qt, I don't know with other backends though.