# fig.show() does not bring the figure up

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)
axe.plot(x,y,'b-')
axe.plot(z,h,'r-')
```

Now, I can see 2 lines (blue and red) plotted on figure. But I accidentally close that figure window.

when I issue command `fig.show(), or fig.draw()`, the figure will never show up again. How can I bring up my original figure without executing above commands again?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code but I'm not getting the output you described. "*2 lines (blue and red) plotted on figure*"

Closing the figure via gui destroys the gui toolkit, however, the figure object still exists, you can save it with `fig.savefig()`. I think the best approach would be re-creating the figure.

Hopefully this helps: [Matplotlib: how to show a figure that has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729948/matplotlib-how-to-show-a-figure-that-has-been-closed).