# Recreate a matplotlib figure from pickle file using a different style file

Tags: matplotlib

I have some figures and axes saved to pickle files using:

```py
pickle.dump((fig, ax), open('myplot.pickle', 'wb'))
```

I'm trying to load this later in a separate file, apply a new style file to it, and export it again:

```py
plt.style.use("some_fancy_style")

fig, ax = pickle.load(open("myplot.pickle", "rb"))

fig.savefig("myplot_different_style.png")
```

But this only picks up a few settings related to `savefig` from the style file. Is there a (relatively easy) way to recreate the plot so that axes/font/grid/etc config are also picked up?

I know even to show the figure after loading the pickle we have to create a new dummy figure and hijack its canvas manager ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31731945/298209)):

```py
new_manager = plt.figure().canvas.manager
new_manager.canvas.figure = fig
fig.set_canvas(new_manager.canvas)
```

I was wondering if similar things could be done for axes/grid/etc?

Comment: I guess this is essentially what this repo from NASA tries to achieve: https://github.com/nasa/mplStyle

It seems to be out of date so couldn't really get it to work

Comment: pickle saves a pretty dead version of the figure.  You are _far_ better to save the data and the script for plotting and recreate that way.