# Pylab animation multiple figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, non-interactive

I want to update multiple figures using pylab animation. I initialize a new figure for each channel to display and I set interactive mode to off using:

```
    pyplot.ion()
    pyplot.show()
```

In the class containing the figure there's a ring buffer and a method to update the data:

```
    def append_data(self, data):
        update buffers with data

        ...
        ...

        self.lineb.set_data(self.tbuf, self.bbuf)
        self.ax1.set_xlim( [min(self.tbuf), max(self.tbuf)] )
        self.ax1.set_ylim( [min(self.bbuf), max(self.bbuf)] )

        ...
        ...

        self.fig.show()
        pyplot.draw()
```

The problem: with more than one figure, only the last one updates correctly. The other ones do not refresh. I know the data is correctly added to the each figure's buffer, so the problem is not there.

Comment: avoid using `pyplot` unless you really are using it interactively.  `fig.canvas.draw()` will do the same thing for a specific figure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. do you mean avoid using `pyplot`command or module? what would you use instead?

Comment: It looks like you are embedding, the event loop of `pyplot` can conflict with the event loop of the your gui.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution following [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure).

I initialized the figure with a name:

```
fig = pyplot.figure(name)
```

and then I changed the lines:

```
    self.fig.show()
    pyplot.draw()
```

to:

```
    pyplot.figure(name)
    pyplot.draw()
```

Apparently this works, not completely sure why.