# Placing Multiple Histograms in Figure with PyLab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a short function as follows:

```
def drawChart(data,title):
    P.title(title)
    P.hist(data, bins=20, histtype='stepfilled')
    P.xlabel("Relevance")
    P.ylabel("Frequency")
    P.savefig(title + '.pdf')
```

This creates a pdf of my histogram. However I make around 6 calls to this, and would ideally like to save them all as one document.

Now firstly how do I collate them all and return an object from the drawChart for this to happen?

I have seen people use figure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure)

Comment: The first thing to do is to go here http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html and find whatever resembles what you want to do.

Comment: Do you want 6 plots in one figure (like http://matplotlib.org/examples/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot_demo.html) or a 6 page pdf?

Comment: I would like a 3x2 figure @Jakob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want `subplots`. A possible example could look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create some data
data = np.random.rand(6,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,2)
ax = ax.reshape(6)
for ind, d in enumerate(data):
  ax[ind].hist(d)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which gives a figure like
[image]

More examples of subplots can be found in the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), e.g. [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_tight_layout.html).