# Dynamicly add a new subplot2grid to a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an application that have 3 figures, and dynamicaly change them. For now it's been working fine by using `add_subplot()` to the figure. But now I have to make my graphs more complex, and need to use `subplot2grid()`

```
self.figure1 = plt.figure()
self.canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)
self.graphtoolbar1 = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas1, frameGraph1)

self.figure3 = plt.figure()
self.canvas3 = FigureCanvas(self.figure3)
self.graphtoolbar3 = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas3, frameGraph3)

self.figure4 = plt.figure()
self.canvas4 = FigureCanvas(self.figure4)
self.graphtoolbar4 = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas4, frameGraph4)
```

And here's the code that adds it, and what I've got so far.

```
#ax = self.figure1.add_subplot(2,1,1) <---- What I used to do

fig = self.figure1
ax = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=4) # <--- what I'm trying to do

ax.hold(False)
ax.plot(df['Close'], 'b-')
ax.legend(loc=0)
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Price")
ax.grid(True)

for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
     tick.set_rotation(20)            

self.canvas1.draw()
```

The above adds it to figure 4. Probably because that's the latest instantiated by plt. But I'd like the above to add a subplot2grid to `self.figure1`, while still having the dynamicly abilities as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the source code of `matplotlib`, the `subplot2grid`-function is defined in the following way:

```
def subplot2grid(shape, loc, rowspan=1, colspan=1, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a subplot in a grid.  The grid is specified by *shape*, at
    location of *loc*, spanning *rowspan*, *colspan* cells in each
    direction.  The index for loc is 0-based. ::

      subplot2grid(shape, loc, rowspan=1, colspan=1)

    is identical to ::

      gridspec=GridSpec(shape[0], shape[2])
      subplotspec=gridspec.new_subplotspec(loc, rowspan, colspan)
      subplot(subplotspec)
    """

    fig = gcf()  #  <-------- HERE
    s1, s2 = shape
    subplotspec = GridSpec(s1, s2).new_subplotspec(loc,
                                                   rowspan=rowspan,
                                                   colspan=colspan)
    a = fig.add_subplot(subplotspec, **kwargs)
    bbox = a.bbox
    byebye = []
    for other in fig.axes:
        if other==a: continue
        if bbox.fully_overlaps(other.bbox):
            byebye.append(other)
    for ax in byebye: delaxes(ax)

    draw_if_interactive()
    return a
```

As you can see from my comment "HERE" in the code snippet, it is only using the active figure, i.e. `fig = gcf()` (gcf is short for "get current figure").

Achieving your goal should be easily done by modifying the function slightly and put it into your script.

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
_backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()

def my_subplot2grid(fig, shape, loc, rowspan=1, colspan=1, **kwargs):

    s1, s2 = shape
    subplotspec = GridSpec(s1, s2).new_subplotspec(loc,
                                                   rowspan=rowspan,
                                                   colspan=colspan)
    a = fig.add_subplot(subplotspec, **kwargs)
    bbox = a.bbox
    byebye = []
    for other in fig.axes:
        if other==a: continue
        if bbox.fully_overlaps(other.bbox):
            byebye.append(other)
    for ax in byebye: delaxes(ax)

    draw_if_interactive()
    return a
```

Now it should be possible to do your thing, with a modification to your function call as

```
ax = plt.my_subplot2grid(self.figure1, (4,4), (0,0), rowspan=3, colspan=4)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out cfg. I found out I could give a number to the figures as I instantiate them. self.figure1 = plt.figure(1) and then set the cfg with plt.figure(1).

Comment: You are right!  I think I overdid it a bit, it should indeed be better to just update the current figure.  The a look at this previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure .   It suggest that you can even call your figures by a string and not just `figure(1)`.