# switch between figure objects in matplotlib - change the active figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Assume we are creating two figures that we need to fill out in a loop.
Here is a toy example (which doesn't work):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(2,2)

for i in np.arange(4):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(0,1,[1,100]), ax=ax)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(-1,1,[1,100]),color='r', ax=ax1)
```

This does not work as `ax = plt.subplot(25, 4, i+1)` will simply refer to the last figure created (fig1) which is currently active and `ax1 = plt.subplot(25, 4, i+1)` will simply create another object referring to the same position which will lead to two plots being generated on the same position.
So, how do I change the active figure?
I had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure) but didn't manage to make it work for my case.

### Current output

The code results in an empty `fig`

[image: fig]

and it plots everything in `fig1`

[image: fig1]

### Desired output

This is how it should behave:

`fig`

[image: fig2]

`fig1`

[image: fig3]

Comment: `ax` and `ax1` are your array of axes for each figure. Use `i` to index these arrays in `displot`. i.e. `sns.distplot(np.random.normal(0,1,[1,100]), ax=ax.flat[i])` and remove `ax = plt.subplot`

Comment: @DavidG this solve my problem (perfectly) but still leaves me wonder if there is a way to switch the active figure after I created the objects with `fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)`,`fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(2,2)`.

Comment: [This may answer your second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `flatten`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax = ax.flatten()
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax1 = ax1.flatten()

for i in np.arange(4):
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(0,1,[1,100]), ax=ax[i])
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(-1,1,[1,100]),color='r', ax=ax1[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of pointers:

1. You are already defining a 2x2 array of axes in ax and ax1 respectively. You dont need to make subplots again inside the loop.
2. You can simply flatten the 2X2 array and iterate over it as an array.
3. You can add the respective axes (ax or ax1) after flattening them to the sns.distplot as axis (ax = flat_ax[i] OR ax = flat_ax1[i])

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(2,2)

#Flatten the n-dim array of ax and ax1
flat_ax = np.ravel(ax)
flat_ax1 = np.ravel(ax1)

#Iterate over them
for i in np.arange(4):
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(0,1,[1,100]), ax=flat_ax[i])
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(-1,1,[1,100]),color='r', ax=flat_ax1[i])
```